# How to prevent MLFlow from automatically creating a run when a logging function is called?

Tags: mlflow

I have a custom model class that calls `mlflow.llm.log_predictions` in the `predict` method like so:

```
class Model:
    ...

    def predict(input) -> Output:
        ...
        mlflow.llm.log_predictions(...)
        ...
```

I'm using that `predict` method in two different contexts:

1. After training, before serializing the model - in order to do cross-validation.
2. After serializing - to serve "production" predictions.

In the first context (cross-val), I wrap all the code in `with mlflow.start_run():` in order to log data into MLFlow.

In the second context (serving), I'd like to suppress all the MLFlow calls and not log anything.

Moving `mlflow.llm.log_predictions` out of `predict` won't work for me, as the LLM I'm using is a submodel in the overall model, so I don't exactly have access to the LLM inputs/outputs outside of `predict`.